# Convert string to typed array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I have a string that should be parsed to JSON and than should be converted to a Float32Array.
The string looks like this:

```
{"vertices":"[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0]"}
```

The Array should be assigned to a variable, e.g.:

```
mesh.vertices = new Float32Array([-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0]);
```

How can I convert the string so that the array consists of float numbers?
For security reasons, I don´t want to use eval().

Comment: Do you mean parsed *as* or *from* JSON? I.e. you have JSON and you  want to convert it to a JavaScript object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [JSON.parse](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON):

```
mesh.vertices = new Float32Array(JSON.parse(myString).vertices);
```

This is assuming you meant:

```
{"vertices":[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0]}
```

If the JSON is actually as you said (which FWIW is a bit weird), it'd be:

```
mesh.vertices = new Float32Array(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(myString).vertices));
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use {"vertices":[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0]} as you proposed.

Comment: There is a good reason for "[ array, items]". It keeps json readable when using simplejson and python. Having 10,000 items in one row or in one column makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON data securely. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON

Answer (score 0):

I still suggest you to use the native `JSON` parser (as others mentioned), but here is a very simple and limited implementation:

```
var stringToParse = "{vertices:[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0]}";

Object.prototype.simpleParse = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof String)) throw "Type mismatch";
    var re = /(\w+)[^:]+:\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
    var keyvalues = re.exec(this.valueOf());
    var key = keyvalues[1];
    var values = keyvalues[2].split(",");
    var arr = [];
    for (val in values) {
        var currentValue = (/-?\d+(.\d+)?/).exec(values[val])[0];
        arr.push(currentValue);
    }
    arr.pop();
    ret = {};
    ret[key] = new Float32Array(arr);
    return ret;
}

console.log(stringToParse.simpleParse());
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mKWGH/